# What is wrong with my ant configuration?

Tags: ant, fedora

I installed Ant on a Fedora 5 machine using yum, but Ant does not launch.  I get this error message:

```
[bash]# ant
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/launch/Launcher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.  Program will exit.
```

I have set the following environment variables:

```
JAVA_HOME = /usr/java/latest
ANT_HOME = /usr/bin
```

Ant is installed at `/usr/bin/ant`.

I have also come across [this post](http://www.karakas-online.de/forum/viewtopic.php?t=9781), and it seems that the `JAVAVER_LIBDIR` variable does not point to something that exists.  I set a symbolic link, like the post suggests cleared the issue up for the author, but it did not fix things for me.

```
[bash]# sudo ln -s /usr/share/java /usr/share/java-1.6.0
```

**Edit:** I have also set a symbolic link that addressed a similar problem with the `JAVAVER_JNIDIR` variable:

```
[bash]# sudo ln -s /usr/lib/java /usr/lib/java-1.6.0
```

I now get a different error message:

```
[bash]# ant --execdebug
/usr/bin/build-classpath: error: Could not find jaxp_parser_impl Java extension for this JVM
/usr/bin/build-classpath: error: Could not find xml-commons-apis Java extension for this JVM
/usr/bin/build-classpath: error: Some specified jars were not found
exec "/usr/java/latest/bin/java" -classpath "/usr/share/java-1.6.0/ant.jar:/usr/share/java-1.6.0/ant-launcher.jar:/usr/java/latest/lib/tools.jar" -Dant.home="/usr" -Dant.library.dir="/usr/lib" org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher -cp ""
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

Off to Google these error messages...

Answer (score 26):

I've just met similar issue on Fedora 18.

To make long story short, run:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/java-1.7.0 /usr/share/java-1.7.0
```

Apparently, this problem is specific to `java-1.7.0-openjdk` because similar *empty* directories for all other JDK versions existed.

---

**DETAILS**

There was single-line error after running `ant`:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher
```

The problem was somewhere in `/usr/share/java-utils/java-functions` script which tried to set `JAVAVER_JNIDIR`/`JAVAVER_LIBDIR` variables to refer to the directories above. Due to inappropriate error message redirection to stdout, some variables got assignments like:

```
LOCALCLASSPATH='/usr/bin/build-classpath: error: JAVAVER_JNIDIR /usr/lib/java-1.7.0 does not exist or is not a directory'
```

Creating the directories according to the convention set by all other java versions is the cleanest solution.

Comment: Thanks!! found using `--execdebug`, same problem occured with me, `classpath` not getting set correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much.  This was driving me insane with java-1.8.0 as well!

Comment: This solution helped me fix the same problem on a Suse SLES11 box - pathes were only slightly different. Yay for `ant --execdebug`!

Answer (score 13):

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/java-1.7.0 /usr/share/java-1.7.0
```

I installed sun java 1.7.x by downloading the tar file and placing it in /opt. Because I didn't do a yum install these directories were not created. My JAVA_HOME is set to:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME/
/opt/jdk1.7.0_03/
```

As someone else said, running the following provided very useful debug:

```
ant --execdebug
```

Answer (score 12):

I think that the ANT_HOME should be set with '/usr/bin/ant'. I have that configuration (CENTOS 5).

My sh script under '/etc/profile.d' has this conf.:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/java";
export ANT_HOME="/usr/local/ant";
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: That was part of the problem.  Thanks.  I still haven't totally fixed everything, but this helped along the way.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem but the following fixed it for me:

```
sudo yum install xml-commons-apis
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error message today, but triggered by a different cause.

In my case, after I updated to OpenJDK 1.8.0, I could no longer run ant.

The problem lied with the fact that the output of the `java -fullversion` command had changed slightly, and the `/usr/share/java-utils/java-functions` no longer correctly understood it.

Upgrading to the latest version of the `jpackage-utils` RPM solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had such problem on Fedora 16 but in my case `xerces` packages and `xml-commons-apis` was ok. Actually, `--execdebug` is very helpful and it printed that ant cannot find a directory at `/usr/lib/jvm-exports/YOUR_JDK`. This was because I switched from openjdk to oracle's jdk and the directory of former version of jdk (`/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0`) left there but there was not the one of my current version (`/usr/lib/jvm-exports/jdk1.6.0_32`). These directories includes only a bunch of soft links that point to particular jre's jars so I've taken following steps:

1. create a new directory for current version of jdk (`jdk1.6.0_32`)
2. copy all links from the openjdk's directory to the new directory 
   `# cp -av java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/* jdk1.6.0_32/`
3. correct all of them so as they are pointing on oracle's jars, example: 
   `# cd /usr/lib/jvm-exports/jdk1.6.0_32
   # ln -s -f $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar jaas-1.6.0.0.jar`

Obviously, `$JAVA_HOME` is set correctly (on the new jdk version).
It solved my problem and can be another cause excepting the causes mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing `xerces-j2-xml-apis`

Comment: This solved the `Could not find xml-commons-apis Java extension for this JVM` error I got using `ant` and JDK 8 on SLES 11 SP4.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was setting my `ANT_HOME` variable, but had `/bin/` appended for use in the system path - this home variable should not be the binary directory, use the following for setting an ant hime, and adding the binary directory to the env path.

```
export ANT_HOME=/opt/apache-ant-1.9.4
export PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Suse, SLES 11. Hidayath's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4849302/1211900 solved it. 
Assuming out-of-the-box package repositories:
    me@sles:~> sudo zypper install xerces-j2-xml-apis

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same error message on OS X, but somebody suggested unsetting ANT_HOME and that worked. 
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/32851

Answer (score 0):

In my case '`lib`' folder which has all jars including

```
ant-launcher.jar
```

was under

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.6/libexec/
```

I copied lib folder under

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.6/
```

because after running 'ant --execdebug' i found ant commands are looking for 'lib' folder under '1.9.6' folder.

after that change ant commands started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Run `which ant` to know if the `ant_home` set. If not please run below with your corresponding paths to set `ant_home`:

```
export ANT_HOME=/ade_autofs/gd29_3rdparty/ANT_1.7.1_GENERIC.rdd/080925/ant 
export PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:${PATH}
```