# unable to run Ant on my mac Os X?

Tags: java, macos, ant

This is what I get after I installed Ant:

```
ant -v
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014
Trying the default build file: build.xml
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

Debug option: (not clear to me)

```
ant --execdebug
exec "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java" -classpath "/Users/sridhar/software_downloads/apache-ant-1.9.4/lib/ant-launcher.jar" -Dant.home="/Users/sridhar/software_downloads/apache-ant-1.9.4" -Dant.library.dir="/Users/sridhar/software_downloads/apache-ant-1.9.4/lib" org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher -cp ""
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

I have set the environment variable correctly:

```
echo $ANT_HOME 
/Users/software_downloads/apache-ant-1.9.4
echo $JAVA_HOME 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I followed this [post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336299/what-is-wrong-with-my-ant-configuration)

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/java-1.7.0 /usr/share/java-1.7.0
```

I still get same error

I am using Mac OS X mavericks and Jdk1.7

Comment: Well, is there a `build.xml` in your current working directory?

Comment: Ant doesn't do a whole lot by itself.  You'll need a script for it to run.  By default, this is `build.xml`, found in the current working directory, but you can make it run other scripts with the `-f` flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in fact running Ant successfully.  `-v` stands for verbose in this case, but I suspect you were thinking it stood for version.  The error message just means you are missing the Ant script file in the current directory, default named `build.xml`.

Create a build script named `build.xml`.  This one just prints the version of Ant.  You would need to modify it to do something more interesting.

```
<project default="print-version">
    <target name="print-version">
        <echo>${ant.version}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

In the same directory as `build.xml`, run `ant`.  You should see something like this printed:

```
print-version:
     [echo] Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on November 8 2012

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Note that Ant is a scripting language.  You have installed the necessary Ant library JARs, but you still need to create your Ant scripts.  A typical Ant script would compile, copy resources, package and JAR your product.

See here for a good tutorial: [Hello World with Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html)

Comment: how would I know if i am running Ant successfully?