# how do you run ant

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to build a jar file using ant like this:

```
CLASSPATH=/files/hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar CFLAGS=-m64 CXXFLAGS=-m64 ant compile-native tar
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher

ant --execdebug
```

show this:

```
exec "/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/java" -classpath "/usr/bin/build-classpath: error: JAVAVER_LIBDIR /usr/share/java-1.8.0 does not exist or is not a directory:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25/lib/tools.jar" -Dant.home="/usr/share/ant" -Dant.library.dir="/usr/share/ant/lib" org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher -cp ""
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher
```

in my /etc/profile.d/java.sh

I have this entries:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/ant
```

Any ideas why I am getting that error and remedy?

Comment: Hi, those two folders are exist right? (I mean the `JAVA_HOME` and `ANT_HOME`) and also, does the user that ran the file has a valid permission?

Comment: @kucing_terbang yes, JAVA_HOME AND ANT_HOME exist. I am running this as root.

Comment: hmm. then could you try the suggestion in this  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336299/what-is-wrong-with-my-ant-configuration)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your main class is in the location you have mentioned..its not able to find your main class

Comment: yes, hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar this file exist and I list the full path to it, your answer is not it.

Comment: when I run ant itself in the command line, I still get that error: "Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher"

Comment: Its not able to find your Launcher class which is i guess your main class, which you have mentioned in your build file..