# `/usr/bin/build-classpath` messages when executing `/usr/bin/groovy`

Tags: groovy, fedora20

```
# groovy --version
/usr/bin/build-classpath: Could not find /lib/jvm/java Java extension for this JVM
/usr/bin/build-classpath: error: Some specified jars were not found
Groovy Version: 1.8.9 JVM: 1.7.0_79 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux

# java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (fedora-2.5.5.0.fc20-x86_64 u79-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

Which "Java extension" do you want me to present to you? "Some specified jars"? I didn't specify any. I really love such meaningless messages.

#### UPDATE 1:

Both of:

```
# alternatives --config java
# alternatives --config javac
```

as described in the [first link of blackdrag's answer](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=736753) didn't help.

For both `There is 1 program that provides 'java[c]'` and it is OpenJDK.

[The second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336299/what-is-wrong-with-my-ant-configuration) didn't help either.

#### UPDATE 2:

I installed and set as alternative:

```
# java -version
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

To no avail.

#### UPDATE 3:

The first message comes from `/usr/share/java-utils/java-functions:`

```
# Functions library for Java applications.                           -*- sh -*-
#
# Copyright (c) 2012-2013, Red Hat, Inc
# All rights reserved.
#
# Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
# modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
# are met:
#
# 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
#    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
# 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
#    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
#    documentation and/or other materials provided with the
#    distribution.
# 3. Neither the name of Red Hat nor the names of its
#    contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
#    from this software without specific prior written permission.
#
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
# "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
# LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
# A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
# OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
# SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
# LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
# DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
# THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
# (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
# OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
#
# Fedora Project <http://www.fedoraproject.org/>
#   Mikolaj Izdebski <mizdebsk@redhat.com>
#
# JPackage Project <http://www.jpackage.org/>
#   Guillaume Rousse <guillomovitch@sourceforge.net>
#   Ville Skyttä <scop at jpackage.org>
#   David Walluck <david@jpackage.org>
#   Nicolas Mailhot <Nicolas.Mailhot at laPoste.net>


_log()
{
    if [ -n "${JAVAPACKAGES_DEBUG}" ]; then
        echo "${0}: ${@}" >&2
    fi
}

_err()
{
    echo "${0}: ${@}" >&2
}

# Load a single Java configuration file.
_load_java_conf_file()
{
    local IFS
    local JAVA_LIBDIR
    local JNI_LIBDIR
    local JVM_ROOT

    if [ -f "${1}" ]; then
        _log "Loading config file: ${1}"
        . "${1}"

        _javadirs="${_javadirs}${_javadirs:+:}${JAVA_LIBDIR}:${JNI_LIBDIR}"
        _jvmdirs="${_jvmdirs}${_jvmdirs:+:}${JVM_ROOT}"
    else
        _log "Skipping config file ${1}: file does not exist"
    fi
}

# Load system and user Java configuration.
_load_java_conf()
{
    local IFS=:
    local java_home_save="${JAVA_HOME}"
    local java_opts_save="${JAVACMD_OPTS}"
    local javaconfdir
    local conf

    unset _javadirs
    unset _jvmdirs

    set -- ${JAVACONFDIRS:-/etc/java}

    _log "Java config directories are:"
    for javaconfdir; do
        _log "  * ${javaconfdir}"
    done

    for javaconfdir; do
        conf="${javaconfdir}/java.conf"
        if [ ! -f "${conf}" ]; then
            _err "Java configuration directory ${javaconfdir} was ignored because configuration file ${conf} does not exist"
        else
            _load_java_conf_file "${conf}"
        fi
    done

    _load_java_conf_file "${HOME}/.java/java.conf"

    _javadirs=${_javadirs:-/usr/share/java:/usr/lib/java}
    _jvmdirs=${_jvmdirs:-/usr/lib/jvm}

    if [ -d "${java_home_save}" ]; then
        JAVA_HOME="${java_home_save}"
    fi
    if [ -n "${java_opts_save}" ]; then
        JAVACMD_OPTS="${java_opts_save}"
    fi
}


# Test default JRE/JVM roots if nothing is defined yet
_set_java_home()
{
    local IFS=:
    local jvmdir
    local subdir
    local subdirs

    if [ -n "${JAVA_HOME}" ]; then
        if [ -z "${JVM_ROOT}" ]; then
            JVM_ROOT=$(readlink -f "${JAVA_HOME}"/.. || :)
        fi
        return
    fi

    case "${_prefer_jre}" in
        1|[Yy][Ee][Ss]|[Tt][Rr][Uu][Ee])
            subdirs=jre:java
            ;;
        *)
            subdirs=java:jre
            ;;
    esac

    for subdir in $subdirs; do
        for jvmdir in $_jvmdirs; do
            JVM_ROOT="${jvmdir}"
            JAVA_HOME="${jvmdir}/${subdir}"
            if [ -d "${JVM_ROOT}" -a -d "${JAVA_HOME}" ]; then
                _log "Using configured JVM_ROOT: ${JVM_ROOT}"
                _log "Using configured JAVA_HOME: ${JAVA_HOME}"
                return
            fi
        done
    done

    unset JVM_ROOT
    unset JAVA_HOME
}

# Set the java virtual machine
set_jvm()
{
    local IFS=:
    local cmd
    local cmds

    _set_java_home

    # use $JAVA_HOME if defined
    if [ -n "${JAVA_HOME}" ]; then
        return
    fi

    # try to find it from java command

    # try javac first, or we might get the location of the jre instead - djw
    # if JRE is prefered then don't try javac - mizdebsk
    case "${_prefer_jre}" in
        1|[Yy][Ee][Ss]|[Tt][Rr][Uu][Ee])
            cmds=java
            ;;
        *)
            cmds=javac:java
            ;;
    esac

    for cmd in $cmds; do
        cmd=$(which "${cmd}" 2>/dev/null || :)

        if [ -n "${cmd}" ]; then
            cmd=$(readlink -f "${cmd}")
            export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f "${cmd%/*}"/.. || :)
            return
        fi
    done

    echo "Can't find Java virtual machine, aborting."
    exit 1
}

# Set the classpath
set_classpath()
{
    local IFS

    _set_java_home

    # get local classpath first
    set -- ${@} ${ADDITIONAL_JARS}
    LOCAL_CLASSPATH=$("/usr/bin/build-classpath" ${@})

    # append original classpath if defined
    CLASSPATH=${LOCAL_CLASSPATH}${CLASSPATH:+:}${CLASSPATH}
}

set_javacmd()
{
    local IFS
    local cmd

    if [ -x "${JAVACMD}" ]; then
        return
    fi

    set_jvm

    # Add all sorts of jvm layouts here
    for cmd in jre/sh/java bin/java; do
        JAVACMD="${JAVA_HOME}/${cmd}"
        if [ -x "${JAVACMD}" ]; then
            _log "Using configured JAVACMD: $JAVACMD"
            JAVACMD="${JAVACMD}${JAVACMD_OPTS:+ }${JAVACMD_OPTS}"
            return 0
        fi
    done

    JAVACMD=$(which java 2>/dev/null || :)
    if [ -x "${JAVACMD}" ]; then
        _log "Using JAVACMD from PATH: $JAVACMD"
        JAVACMD="${JAVACMD}${JAVACMD_OPTS:+ }${JAVACMD_OPTS}"
        return 0
    fi

    _err "Failed to set JAVACMD"
    return 1
}

# Set flags
set_flags()
{
    FLAGS="${@}${ADDITIONAL_FLAGS:+ }${ADDITIONAL_FLAGS}"
}

# Set options
set_options()
{
    OPTIONS="${@}${ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS:+ }${ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS}"
}

# Run application
run()
{
    set_javacmd

    if [ -n "${VERBOSE}" ]; then
        echo "Java virtual machine used: ${JAVACMD}"
        echo "classpath used: ${CLASSPATH}"
        echo "main class used: ${MAIN_CLASS}"
        echo "flags used: ${FLAGS}"
        echo "options used: ${OPTIONS}"
        echo "arguments used: ${@}"
    fi

    # let's start
    exec "${JAVACMD}" ${FLAGS} -classpath "${CLASSPATH}" \
        ${OPTIONS} "${MAIN_CLASS}" "${@}"
}

# Set JVM-related directories
set_jvm_dirs()
{
    local IFS
    local re
    local option
    local version

    _set_java_home

    # Jar repository provided by the JVM
    JVM_LIBDIR=${JVM_ROOT}-exports/$(echo "${JAVA_HOME}" |\
        sed -n "s+${JVM_ROOT}/\([-_[:alnum:].]*\)\(.*\)+\1+p")

    # Java standard version of the JVM.  -fullversion seems to be lot faster
    # to invoke than -version.  Some examples:
    #   java full version "1.4.2_04-b05"
    #   java full version "J2RE 1.4.1 IBM build cxia321411-20030930"
    #   java full version "Blackdown-1.4.1-01"
    #   java version "1.5.0"

    re='\([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\.[[:digit:]]\{1,\}\(\.[[:digit:]]\{1,\}\)*\)'
    for option in -fullversion -version; do
        # Yuck, "grep -o" would be cleaner, but requires GNU grep >= 2.5.
        # This could be improved/simplified if sed had non-greedy matching.
        version=$(${JAVACMD} $option 2>&1 | sed -n \
            -e '/\(openjdk\|java\) \(full \)*version "/s/'$re'/<<<\1>>>/' \
            -e '/\(openjdk\|java\) \(full \)*version "/s/.*<<<\([^>]\{1,\}\)>>>.*/\1/p')
        if [ -n "${version}" ]; then
            _log "Determined Java version to be ${version}"
            break
        fi
    done

    if [ -z "${version}" ]; then
        echo "$0: Unable to determine Java version"
        return 1
    fi

    # Jar repository for this Java standard
    IFS=:
    _javaverdirs=
    for dir in ${_javadirs}; do
        _javaverdirs="${_javaverdirs}${_javaverdirs:+:}${dir}-${version}"
   done

    return 0
}


# Links a jar repository
link_jar_repository() {

   unset repository
   unset extension_list

   unset _LINK_CMD
   unset _PRESERVE_NAMING

   while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
      case "$1" in
         -h|--hard)
            _LINK_CMD="ln -f"
            ;;
         -s|--soft|--symbolic)
            _LINK_CMD="ln -fs"
            ;;
         -c|--copy)
            _LINK_CMD="cp -f"
            ;;
         -p|--preserve-naming)
            _PRESERVE_NAMING="true"
            [ -z "$_LINK_CMD" ] && _LINK_CMD="cp -f"
            ;;
         --|-)
            break
            ;;
         *)
            if [ -z "$repository" ] ; then
               repository=$1
               if ! [ -d "$repository" -a -w "$repository" ] ; then
                  _err "$1 must be a writable directory"
                  exit 1
               fi
            else
               extension_list="$extension_list $1"
            fi
            ;;
      esac
      shift
   done

   [ -z "$_LINK_CMD" ] && _LINK_CMD="ln -fs"
   extension_list="$extension_list $@"

   pushd $repository > /dev/null
      _ALLFOUND=0
      for extension in $extension_list ; do
         extension=$(echo $extension | sed 's+/$++g' | sed 's+\.jar$++g')
         found_extension=$(find_jar $extension)
         found=$?
         [ -z "$_PRESERVE_NAMING" ] \
            && extension=[$(echo $extension | sed 's+/+][+g')] \
            || extension=$(echo $extension | sed 's+/+_+g')
         if [ $found -eq 0 ] ; then
            if [ -d "$found_extension" ] ; then
               for jar in $(find "$found_extension" -follow -name "*.jar") ; do
                  rm -fr "$extension$(basename $jar)"
                  $_LINK_CMD $jar "$extension$(basename $jar)"
               done
            else
               rm -fr $extension.jar
               $_LINK_CMD $found_extension $extension.jar
            fi
         else
            # Defer failure to get list of all errors in one shot
            # Do create a symlink so we can recover with another jvm
            rm -fr $extension.jar
            ln -fs /could/not/find/extension/for/this/jvm $extension.jar
            _ALLFOUND=1
         fi
      done
   popd $repository > /dev/null
   return $_ALLFOUND
}


# Finds a specific extention (jar or directory)
find_jar()
{
    local IFS=:
    local artifact="${1}"
    local m2home="${M2_HOME:-/usr/share/xmvn}"

    # If artifact contains semicolon then assume it specifies Maven
    # artifact coordinates.
    set -- ${artifact}
    if [ ${#} -gt 1 ]; then
        _log "Using XMvn location: ${m2home}"
        if ! [ -x "${m2home}/bin/xmvn-resolve" ]; then
            echo "${0}: Unable to execute xmvn-resolve." >&2
            echo "${0}: Make sure that XMvn is installed and M2_HOME is set correctly." >&2
            return 1
        fi

        "${m2home}/bin/xmvn-resolve" -c "${artifact}"
        return ${?}
    fi

    set -- ${JVM_LIBDIR} ${_javaverdirs} ${_javadirs}

    _log "JAR search path is:"
    for dir; do
        _log "  * ${dir}"
    done

    for artifact in ${artifact%.jar} ${artifact%-*} ${artifact%/*}; do
        for dir; do
            _log "Trying file ${dir}/${artifact}.jar"
            if [ -r "${dir}/${artifact}.jar" ]; then
                echo "${dir}/${artifact}.jar"
                return 0
            fi
            _log "Trying dir  ${dir}/${artifact}/"
            if [ -d "${dir}/${artifact}" ]; then
                echo "${dir}/${artifact}"
                return 0
            fi
        done
    done

    _err "Could not find ${artifact} Java extension for this JVM"
    return 1
}


## Checks java environment
check_java_env()
{
    # This is usually set by set_jvm
    if [ -z "${JAVA_HOME}" ]; then
        _err "JAVA_HOME must be set"
        return 1
    fi

    if [ -z "${JAVACMD}" ]; then
        _err "JAVACMD must be set"
        return 2
    fi

    return 0
}


_load_java_conf
```

The second message comes directly from `/usr/bin/build-classpath:`

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Small script to build a classpath depending on the JVM used
#
# JPackage Project <http://www.jpackage.org/>
#
# $Id: build-classpath,v 1.2 2005/09/17 07:06:19 david Exp $

# Import java functions
[ -r "/usr/share/java-utils/java-functions" ] \
 &&  . "/usr/share/java-utils/java-functions" || exit 1

# Prints help message
usage() {
cat >&2 << EOF_USAGE
Usage: $0 <jar1> [<jar2> .. <jarn>]
jarX: name of a jar
      Example: jndi
EOF_USAGE
exit 2
}

[ "$#" -eq "0" ] && usage

set_javacmd || exit 3

check_java_env || exit 4

set_jvm_dirs || exit 5

_ALLFOUND="true"

for extension in "$@" ; do
    unset _JARS
    extension=$(find_jar $extension)
    if [ "$?" = 0 ] ; then
        if [ -d "$extension" ] ; then
            # Brute-force approach. If we can't specify a single jar, we can as
            # well take everything in the directory
            # This may create duplicates if symlinks point back inside the
            # directory structure, but who cares
            _JARS=$(find "$extension" -follow -name "*.jar" -type f -printf %p: 2>/dev/null)
        else
            _JARS=$extension:
        fi
        _CLASSPATH=$_CLASSPATH$_JARS
    else
        # Defer failure to get list of all errors in one shot
        _ALLFOUND="false"
    fi
done

# Cleanup trailing :
_CLASSPATH="$(echo $_CLASSPATH | sed 's+:$++g')"

# Echo classpath whether it's complete or not
# Apps that do not care about a full classpath can redirect errors to /dev/null
echo "$_CLASSPATH"

if [ "$_ALLFOUND" = "true" ] ; then
    exit 0
else
    echo "$0: error: Some specified jars were not found" >&2
    exit 6
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your Java installation is messed up. [This text from Redhat here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=736753) suggest configuring using alternatives tools to select the OpenJDK only. Further tries to fix this are noted in this stackoverflow question ["What is wrong with my ant configuration?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336299/what-is-wrong-with-my-ant-configuration). But it seems to boil down to not to install the oracle JDK.

EDIT:
As per comments I add this workaround to my answer in case those links do not help: That is to download the zip from [groovy-lang.org/download.html](http://groovy-lang.org/download.html) unpack it, set JAVA_HOME to the correct JDK directory and use the shell scripts in there instead. On the page is also a description for GVM, which is a bit more comfortable to use to install Groovy than the pure zip. Still this bypasses the proper installation on Fedora, so it is supposed to be used only if nothing else works, or if you want only a local installation.

Comment: So maybe it is not your java, but your groovy installation that is messed up then. I can only suggest a workaround and that would be to use the zip distribution from http://www.groovy-lang.org/download.html and use that instead. Since your Java is working, you may have to set JAVA_HOME, but otherwise you should be able to use groovy directly from that zip. I did not suggest this in the beginning, since you tried the system variant and the package manager. But since those things fail so badly...

Comment: Many thanks for the link! If you make it an answer I'll accept it. If not I'm going to accept my own.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling FC's Groovy and following the instructions at [Groovy, Download, GVM (the Groovy enVironment Manager)](http://www.groovy-lang.org/download.html) (Many thanks to [blackdrag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938573/blackdrag)!) did the trick:

```
# yum erase groovy
...
# curl -s get.gvmtool.net | bash
...
# source "/root/.gvm/bin/gvm-init.sh"
# gvm install groovy
...
# groovy -version
Groovy Version: 2.4.4 JVM: 1.8.0_51 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
```